# SQL Server - Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, join

Here are my tables

```
  StudentID    Name
    ----------   ------
      1          Mary
      2          John
      3          Peter
      4          Edwards

   ClassID      StudentIDs
    --------    -----------
      1          1,2
      2          3,4

    **Output Expected**

    ClassID   Names
    -------   -------

        1      Mary,John
        2      Peter,Edwards
```

Comment: if you can do something, try to normalize your base first. It's a really bad idea to have something like StudentIDs : values comma separated

Comment: You'll need to first split the values in your Class to Student table into a 1:1 ClassID to StudentID. Once that's accomplished, it'd be a straight INNER JOIN between the sets. Then you'd need to pack that data back into your column. Plenty of examples of how to do this on this site

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus i don't have rights to change the table structure. suggest me solution without changing the table structure...

Comment: Yes my lord ;) Seriously : what have you tried, can you show us an example of an existing insert, update query on this structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not hard, even the information in your table does not seems to be stored correctly:

```
SELECT  ClassID
       ,(SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + Name FROM @TableOne WHERE Students LIKE '%'+CAST(StudentID AS NVARCHAR(5))+'%' ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH('')),2,200) AS CSV)
FROM @TableTwo
```

And you can use this code (copy/paste) for working example:

```
DECLARE @TableOne TABLE
(
    StudentID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @TableTwo TABLE
(
    ClassID INT,
    Students NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TableOne (StudentID,Name)
VALUES  (1,'Mary')
       ,(2,'John')
       ,(3,'Peter')
       ,(4,'Edwards')
       ,(5,'Pepe')
       ,(6,'C.Ronaldo')
       ,(7,'Zidane')
       ,(8,'Raul')

INSERT INTO @TableTwo (ClassID,Students)
VALUES  (1,'1,3,5,6,8')
       ,(2,'2,4,7')


SELECT  ClassID
       ,(SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + Name FROM @TableOne WHERE Students LIKE '%'+CAST(StudentID AS NVARCHAR(5))+'%' ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH('')),2,200) AS CSV)
FROM @TableTwo
```

Answer (score 2):

I  would strongly suggest you to change your way of storing the StudentIDs in the second table

You could do like this:

```
ClassID      StudentIDs
    --------    -----------
      1          1
      1          2
      2          3
      2          4
```

then we can use the query, to get the output

```
SELECT ClassID , Names= 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Names
           FROM Studentb 
           WHERE b.ClassID      = a.ClassID      
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Studenta
GROUP BY ClassID
```

Comment: i don't have rights to change the table structure. suggest me solution without changing the table structure...

Comment: @Madhu: you dont have to change the table structure, you just have to change the way you store in the table

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to create a SQL function.

```
Create Procedure GetStudent
as
  select ClassID , dbo.fnGetNamesById(StudentIDs) 
  from Table2
go

 create function fnGetNamesById (@psCSString as varchar(500))
  returns varchar(max)    
  as
Begin
    DECLARE @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(20))
    DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(100)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                        LEN(@psCSString)))
      SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString), 0),
                                   LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
      INSERT INTO @otTemp VALUES (ltrim(@sTemp))
    End
    set @sTemp = ''
    select @sTemp = @sTemp + Name from table1 where StudentID    in (select sID from @otTemp)

    return @sTemp
End
```